# ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I am getting this error:

```
'could not obtain a database connection within 5 seconds (waited 5.001017 seconds). The max pool size is currently 16; consider increasing it.'
```

First I got this error, I bumped up the count from 5 to 16. But it's still happening and i am the only one test out the database. Why is this happening when I am the only user?

I am not on rails btw. I am using:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection ({
    :adapter => 'mysql2',
    :database => 'ck',
    :host => 'localhost',
    :username => 'root',
    :password => '',
    :pool => 16,
    })
```

and using Sinatra.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Frederick pointed out you need to return opened ActiveRecord connections to the connection pool.

If you're using the Thin server, in threaded mode, then you need to add this to your Sinatra app:

```
after do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close
end
```

...instead of using the ConnectionManagement suggestion. The reason is that Thin splits the request processing over 2 threads and the thread that is closing the ActiveRecord connection is not the same as the thread that opened it.  As ActiveRecord tracks connections by thread ID it gets confused and won't return connections correctly.

Comment: @squixy - put this in whatever class in your app extends `Sinatra::Base`

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close` instead of `ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!` as specified in the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html)?  Is this simply out of date?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you are not returning connections to the pool at the end of the request. If not then each request that uses the db will consume 1 connection and eventually you'll exhaust the pool and start getting the error messages you describe

Active Record provides a rack middleware to handle this `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement`, which should take care of things as long as its earlier in the middleware chain than anything that will access active record.

You can also take care of the connection management yourself. The [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html) have more details but one way of doing it is sticking all of your db accesses in a block like this

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
  ...
end
```

Which checks out a connection at the start of the block and checks it back in afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. Should I call this before ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection ?

Comment: It's the first thing I call in my script, but still getting the same error :(

Comment: What do you mean by "calling it"? Are you adding it to the middleware stack ? (The Sinatra docs have examples iirc)

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use the [middleware](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8f218266bb4fa4ef2a07904b106c72fda9e182a6/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb#L616) provided with ActiveRecord:

```
use ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement
```

Answer (score 0):

As Frederick pointed out you need to return opened ActiveRecord connections to the connection pool.

As kuwerty suggests, when you are using Thin, `ConnectionManagement` will not return connections to the pool. I suggest that instead of closing the current connection like kuwerty says, you return the connection to the pool like so.

```
after do
  ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!
end
```

For those who want to reproduce the problem, try [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36697685/how-do-i-reuse-connections-in-activerecord).

EDIT:

I made an explanation of why using middleware `ActiveRecord::Connectionadapters::ConnectionManagement` won't work with Thin in threaded mode, which you can find [here](http://ruslanledesma.com/2016/04/23/release-connections-thin-and-active-record.html).