# Rails application unexpectedly throwing errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It's such a strange occurrence. I can go to the same page three times, and 1 out of those 3 times, the page will throw an error.

Is this a common thing amongst rails applications? 
Is this caused by me having an incorrect setting somewhere for caching?

I understand that there isn't much context here, but I feel like it's a common occurrence.

I can't exactly copy paste my entire application.

My error logs read:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError (could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds)):
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:189:in `block in wait_poll'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:180:in `loop'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:180:in `wait_poll'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:135:in `block in poll'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:145:in `synchronize'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:133:in `poll'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:425:in `acquire_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
```

Comment: No, it's not a common occurrence.

Comment: Oh, well that's scary.

Comment: You might be exhausting your database connection pool with too many threads (if you're using a threaded server such as Puma) and a connection pool that's too small. Please post your `database.yml` and your Rails server configuration.

Comment: it would also help what page you were trying to load.  controller code and the template would help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675879/activerecordconnectiontimeouterror)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a Rails error:

> ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError (**could not obtain a database connection** within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds))

It's an issue with your database connectivity:

- Trying to load too much data (IE hitting the DB for 1000+ records in seconds)
- Have an extremely high latency (slow) connection
- Have too many open database connections on your system (preventing more from loading)

---

The way to resolve this will be a debug procedure:

-

**DB**

How are your database(s) hosted?

We use a shared host to store some MYSQL db's for development (we like to keep our setup lean), and have on-site db hosting (same datacenter) for production apps.

A database server is literally just like requesting JSON objects -- [SQL delivers "data" in XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL/XML), meaning that if you're requesting it from a system *other than* the localhost, you need to measure how fast/slow it's returning.

Your problem might be that your system is taking too long to connect to your DB, thus refreshing might be preventing it from accessing it again. The only way to fix this is to get a setup which is geographically close...

[image]

We've had this problem with Heroku before -- using external MYSQL db's slowed the system down massively :)

Using something like RackSpace allows you to connect to database servers located in the same datacenter...

[image]

-

**Dataset**

Following on from the above, the second issue you may have is that you're calling massive amounts of data.

Remember, a db server is just a computer, answering your request with data.

As such, if you're calling reams of data in one call, the time required to process it will be substantial (preventing further requests from being handled).

You need to be realistic with your data requests - we tend to stick to perhaps 100 objects in one call, and you have to avoid [n+1 queries](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/n_plus_one/) like the plague.

-

**Pool Size**

Finally, the *pool size* of the database connections is another point of consideration.

You can read about this here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections

In short, it should be the case that you're limiting your db connections to only the ones which your app needs. Any superfluous ones will just be causing issues.

Comment: I think the problem may be in my pool size. It's set to 5 (the default). I assume I need a much higher number.